# Shell Script : MongoDB Dump

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, shell, sh

I'm creating a shell script to automatically dump the database. I have the current code below.

```
#!/bin/sh
FILENAME=backup_`date +%m%d%y%H`.zip
DEST=/backup/$FILENAME
SERVER=127.0.0.1:27017
mongodump -h $SERVER -d "database-cms" --archive=$DEST --gzip
```

The problem is when I'm opening the zip file it shows a single binary file. Usually, when I dump manually it consists of bson and json files. I don't know what I'm doing wrong I'm expecting a zip file with bson and json file.

**UPDATE**
Turns out that --archive returns binary file. I updated the codes to:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILENAME=configurator_`date +%m%d%y%H`.tar.gz
DEST=/home/glenn/projects/database_dump/backup
SERVER=127.0.0.1:27017

mongodump -h $SERVER -d siaphaji-cms --out $DEST;

tar -zcvf $FILENAME siaphaji-cms
```

The problem is how can I specifically tar the siaphaji-cms folder. The way it runs now is when its compressing it compress all inside backup folder.

Comment: I'm no expert, but are you sure that you use `--archive` when you manually dump it, and not `--out`?

Comment: I think `mongodump` always creates a binary file. Maybe you are looking for `mongoexport` tool?

Comment: Yeah it does create binary file I change it to --out. The only problem left is how I tar that file. I will update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually **works as designed** when you use `--archive`.

The alternative is to provide a `path` to `--out`, which will then give you individual BSON & JSON files ... you'd have to manually GZIP those (or tar the resulting subdirectory/ies.

Comment: Does that mean that I can restore the binary file? Cause I tried to look at if I can restore a binary file and I can't find a way to do it. That's why I thought Im having sort of a problem

Comment: That's at least what the manual for `mongorestore` (checked for 4.2) says ... I haven't tried it, though. The mongodb we have at work is so old that it doesn't know `--archive` so I can't verify it.